# Is there a technique I can use to call a function using the arguments of the function it was called from?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

As you can see, I'm currently taking the `previousResult` and `mutationResult` and passing them in to `deletePostUpdateQuery` every time. I was wondering if there was a cleaner to way to just throw all of the arguments of the `(this function args) => deletePostUpdateQuery(...this function args, key)`.

---

```
updateQueries: {
  NewPosts: (previousResult, { mutationResult }) => deletePostUpdateQuery(previousResult, mutationResult, 'newPosts'),
  HotPosts: (previousResult, { mutationResult }) => deletePostUpdateQuery(previousResult, mutationResult, 'hotPosts'),
  NotificationPosts: (previousResult, { mutationResult }) => deletePostUpdateQuery(previousResult, mutationResult, 'notificationPosts'),
  OwnPosts: (previousResult, { mutationResult }) => deletePostUpdateQuery(previousResult, mutationResult, 'ownPosts'),
},
```

---

```
const deletePostUpdateQuery = (previousResult, mutationResult, key) => {
  const deletedPostEdgeIndex = _.findIndex(previousResult[key].feed.edges, {
    node: {
      id: mutationResult.data.deletePost.id,
    },
  });

  const result = update(previousResult, {
    [key]: {
      feed: {
        edges: {
          $splice: [[deletedPostEdgeIndex, 1]],
        },
      },
    },
  });

  return result;
};
```

Comment: [**Function.prototype.apply**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: Not with the above, no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make a wrapping caller function. For example:

```
const callDPUQ = key => (previousResult, { mutationResult }) => 
  deletePostUpdateQuery(previousResult, mutationResult, key)
```

Then you can write your update object like this:

```
updateQueries: {
  NewPosts: callDPUQ('newPosts'),
  HotPosts: callDPUQ('hotPosts'),
  NotificationPosts: callDPUQ('notificationPosts'),
  OwnPosts: callDPUQ('ownPosts')
}
```

To explain, calling `callDPUQ` returns a function itself, which utilises the key passed in.

Comment: Really clean and taught me a cool, useful, new pattern. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you can change the signature of `deletePostUpdateQuery` to put the `key` up front and to destructure `mutationResult`:

```
const deletePostUpdateQuery = (key, previousResult, {mutationResult}) => {
    // ...
};
```

then you can use `bind`:

```
updateQueries: {
  NewPosts: deletePostUpdateQuery.bind(null, 'newPosts'),
  HotPosts: deletePostUpdateQuery.bind(null, 'hotPosts'),
  NotificationPosts: deletePostUpdateQuery.bind(null, 'notificationPosts'),
  OwnPosts: deletePostUpdateQuery.bind(null, 'ownPosts'),
},
```

Otherwise (or if you just don't want to), your own curry-esque function [as Matt Way suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43195776/157247) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop to define your object with `Object.assign`:

```
updateQueries: Object.assign(...['New', 'Hot', 'Notification', 'Own'].map(
    key => ({ 
        [key + 'Posts']: (previousResult, { mutationResult }) => 
            deletePostUpdateQuery(previousResult, mutationResult, key.toLowerCase() + 'Posts') 
    })
));
```